# Return sum 0 if no records found mysql

Tags: mysql

I want this query to return a sum of 0 for `total` if a record in `users` table does not exist in `securitydeposits` table. `COALESCE` does not work for this scenario. How would I go about this?

```
SELECT users.`email`,
  COALESCE(SUM(securitydeposits.`amount_paid`),0) AS total 
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `securitydeposits` 
  ON securitydeposits.user=users.email 
GROUP BY securitydeposits.`user` 
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `GROUP BY` is changing the `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Try changing `GROUP BY securitydeposits.user` to `GROUP BY users.email`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add what @Vatev said, you cannot use `s.user` for `group by`, because  the `left join` will give you `null` for `s.user` which do not match with `u.email`. 
Also if you want to use `email` in select clause, you need to `group by` it also to get correct result.

Also try to use `alias` for table names as best practice, so you can refer to them in rest of the query.

```
SELECT u.email 
,COALESCE(SUM(s.`amount_paid`),0) 
AS total 
FROM `users` u
  LEFT JOIN `securitydeposits` s
ON s.user=u.email 
GROUP BY u.email 
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```